# MPAndroidChart customizing horizontal BarChart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

Here is a picture of the barchart. As you can see there is an alignment issue, the bars are not aligning with the labels particularly in the mid section. In addition I want the bottom Axis to show the bars in 10's not 1.2, 1.4, 1.6 etc as there will never be any decimals so its not useful. I would also like the value of each bar to be shown at the end as a number to show the total count for each bar.

Picture of chart
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tqir.jpg

Styling

```
 // All JSON entries form the MYSQL server are parsed into an ArrayList.
    moodEntries = new ArrayList<>();

    // For loop which dynamically adds all entries to the ArrayList
    for (MoodStatsPieChartModel moodLogPieChartResponse : moodStatsPieChartModels) {

        moodEntries.add(new BarEntry(moodLogPieChartResponse.getMoodBefore(), moodLogPieChartResponse.getMoodCount()));
    }
 -- the .getmoodBefore() will be an int value from 1 - 18 which represents a mood 
    and the .getmoodCount() just totals how much of each mood. 
    This data is stored in the internal sqlite database.
}

 // custom X-axis labels
    String[] values = new String[] { "Excited", "Happy", "Confident", "Proud", "Content", "Fine", "Relaxed", "Calm", "Tired", "Guilty", "Sad", "Depressed", "Embarrassed", "Upset", "Stressed", "Anxious", "Confused", "Disgusted"};

    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(moodEntries, "");
    barDataSet.setColors(color);
    barDataSet.setValueTextSize(16f);
    barDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    BarData data = new BarData(barDataSet);
    //barData.setBarWidth(1f);
    data.setValueTextSize(10f);


    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setLabelCount(values.length, true);
    xAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(values));
    xAxis.setGranularity(10f);
    //xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    //xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    //xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    //xAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
    //xAxis.setAxisMaximum(values.length);
    //barChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    //xAxis.setAxisMinimum(values.length);


    // Top Axis
    YAxis yAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
    yAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    yAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    //yAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    yAxis.setDrawLabels(false);
    //yAxis.setAxisMaximum(0f);
    //yAxis.setDrawGridLinesBehindData(false);


    // Bottom Axis
    YAxis yAxisBottom = chart.getAxisRight();
    yAxisBottom.setDrawGridLines(false);
    yAxisBottom.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    //yAxisBottom.setGranularity(10f);
    //yAxisBottom.setDrawGridLinesBehindData(false);
    //yAxisBottom.setDrawLabels(true);
    //yAxisBottom.setAxisMinimum(2f);


    Legend l = chart.getLegend();
    l.setEnabled(false);
    chart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    chart.animateXY(1000, 1000);
    chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    chart.setExtraOffsets(-10, -10, -10, -10);
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    chart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    chart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
    //chart.setFitBars(true);
    //chart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(100);



    chart.setData(data);
    chart.invalidate();
```

Comment: How do you fill the moodEntries?

Comment: I updated the question to include the arraylist used to populate the Entries. Its basically just two values - the mood value which ranges form 1-18 and the mood count. This data comes from the database.

Comment: mostly mood count is 1.0 as seen in the image?

Comment: Yeah when the app loads for the first time I automatically insert 1 value for each of the 18 moods into the database so the graph will display properly.

Comment: If i do not do this, and I manually add one mood value on its own, there will be one HUGE bar covering the entire screen which looks crazy

Comment: You can change value formatter of yAxisBottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public class ValFormatter extends ValueFormatter {


    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
        if(value == Math.round(value)){ // value is an integer?
            return String.valueOf((int) value);
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
yAxisBottom.setValueFormatter(new ValFormatter())
```

Because yAxis shows you a range. This way you can fix it.

You can try these lines for value of bar:

```
data.setValueTextSize(10f)
data.setDrawValues(true)
```

Comment: ValueFormatter is not a class which we can extend, I see IAXISValueFormatter or IValueFormatter

Comment: import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.ValueFormatter;     -> I'm using this

Comment: That appears to have fixed the values on the bottom line :
https://imgur.com/gallery/ENPESbu
Any thoughts on how to get the number to display at the end of each bar?
And how to align the bars, thank you for your help so far, it's greatly appreciated!!